# Does csplit read fully line into memory if not required?

Tags: csplit

Suppose I have a 100GB file that I want to split into parts, the different parts being separated by a fixed marker. The marker is just a fixed string of about 20 character, and hence the regex to match is just /MARKER/.

Given this low-complexity regex, if I run

```
csplit file /MARKER/
```

I would hope csplit only reads the files in small chunks to keep its memory foodprint low.
Does it actually do that? Or will it read the full file into memory and then process the whole contents from memory?

Comment: that would depend on your individual implementation of `csplit`. But, usually, regex engines only keep the context they need  – so, essentially, at most the last 19 characters.